# Do I need another view controller for new UIView in same window?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a TabBar app (no Storyboards) with a UIView in the first window that effectively uses 1/2 of the vertical space. It has a background color which belongs to that view only.

I need to add another UIView in the lower half, with a different background color.

Currently, there is only one view controller; do I have to add another view controller for the lower view so I have addressability?  Or is there a different way of accomplishing this?

Comment: What's going to be in your new UIView? You don't need a controller per view, but if it is totally unrelated to the model and functions of the top half, it could make more sense to have it as a separate controller.

Comment: The top half contains a calendar; when the user clicks a day, information about that day is displayed on the bottom half... the calendar has orange days (user asked for that!)...the bottom half contains a schedule of information about that day, with a white background.

Comment: jrjurton is 100% correct, that's answer-worthy. I'll add that UILabel's, UIButton's etc.. are all views themselves but since they are usually related to model and functionality of their container view, the same view controller is used.

Comment: That's sounds pretty related, not unlike nav and detail views in a split-view contoller. I'd say one VC will do. Unless the detail pane has a LOT of it's own code, and the only thing you pass it is the day in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether the control does any 'logic'. If it is just a generic calendar display I would make it an UIView subclass, since UIViews are just that, *views*. Create a delegate for it to pass along 'events' and handle all the other logic in the UIViewController. This makes for better reusability since it creates a generic display.

If it does contain any logic like loading and processing data I would make it a controller. From what you said though, it sounds like a view would be more appropriate imho.

Comment: Attaching the second UIView to the same controller as the calendar gives me two calendars... I think I need another controller, right?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I thought you wanted some calendar view inside the view of the UIViewController. If so, you just add your CalendarView as a subview to the main view.

Comment: Sorry, let me try to clarify it... I have a UIView Controller that has one UIView for the calendar.  The calendar takes up the top 1/2 of the view.  I need to add another UIView below the calendar.  I can't use the calendar's controller, because it gives me another calendar.  I think I need a separate VC for the lower UIView, right?

Comment: If the calendar already has a controller then you should not use that one. Instead, use a new one or use the 'parent' UIViewController that controls the *whole* view.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add another ViewController to interface with a new UIView in an existing view.

If you are using Interface Builder, just drag a new **View** object (which is just a UIView) from the gallery onto the canvass and size appropriately. To get a reference to this view in your existing view controller, bring up the assistant editor and ctrl-drag from the new view to your view controller implementation file (*.m). You can now manipulate the new UIView from your existing view controller.